# How to create customized Views for AppWidgets?

Tags: android

There is a given set of predefinied Views that can be used in layouts for AppWidgets. How can a customized View added to this list?
The minimum requirement is that the class is annotated with RemoteView. What else is necessary to be acceptable as view in the layout.xml?

Answer (score 4):

You cannot use custom views as RemoteViews and it is not currently planned.

Comment: And the documentation is here, for reference: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#CreatingLayout

Comment: How did HTC get customized views in their widgets?

Comment: Just like we did for the Search widget in the default open source Home screen: it's built in the Home screen.

Comment: Roman & Romain, can you elaborate why it is not possible to use custom views, or at least construct the RemoteViews programmatically ?